# Script/formula that outputs a word position in a list of words that seperated by a comma

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got a cell with a lot of words separated by commas, and I would like to input one of the words (in another cell) and the specific word's position in the list would be outputed to a 3rd cell. Example -

[image: example cell list]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what yo tried adn add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myfunc101() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h] = i; });
  let vO = vs.map((r, i) => {
    return [r[idx['list']].toString().split(',').indexOf(r[idx['search item']]) + 1];
  });
  sh.getRange(2, idx['position in list'] + 1, vO.length, vO[0].length).setValues(vO);
}
```

My Sheet:

| list | search item | position in list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| one,two,three,four,five,six | one | 1 |
| one,two,three,four,five,six | two | 2 |
| one,two,three,four,five,six | three | 3 |
| one,two,three,four,five,six | four | 4 |
| one,two,three,four,five,six | five | 5 |
| one,two,three,four,five,six | six | 6 |

[Array Destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: Thank you Cooper that really helps, I've managed to work it into my sheet, apologies for my lack of scripting/coding skills :)
I've figured the data I have under 'list' has spaces so initially that didnt work until I removed those after each comma. Is there a way to modify it to be non-sensitive as well?

Comment: It could have been easier to code but I didn't know what the columns were in your example so I used the header indices instead.

Comment: If the column names are known, how would that be reflected in the code? an 'if' condition for sh.getDataRange('A6') for example?

Comment: You can answer you own question by studying the code.

Comment: I've been using the code with a bit modification (mainly to return an empty cell if the value turns to be 0), but i found out that when i input the 'list', 'search item' and 'position' in any row but 1, the function fails. is it possible to have it work on rows below a certain value?

Comment: I don't understand the function I wrote does not return anything.  It just calculates a position.  If the position is zero just means that the search item was not found in the list.